# When a word matches retrieve the varying string after it

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, split, match

I have a query which looks like this:

```sql
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.xx = TableB.xx
INNER JOIN TableC
ON TableA.yy = TableC.yy
```

I am trying to write a script which selects the tables which come after the word "JOIN".

The script that I wrote now is:

```bsh
$data = Get-Content -Path query1.txt
$dataconv = "$data".ToLower() -replace '\s+', ' '
$join = 0

$overigetabellen = ($dataconv) | foreach {
    if ($_ -match "join (.*)") {
        $join++
        $join = $matches[1].Split(" ")[0]  
        #Write-Host "Table(s) on which is joined:" $join"."
        $join
    }
}
$overigetabellen
```

This gives me only the first table, so TableB.
Can anyone help me how I get the second table also as output?

Comment: Are you looking for `(Get-Content -Path query1.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match 'JOIN'}) -replace '^.*JOIN\s(.*)$','$1'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my naive attempt to find the desired table names.

Split the data input on whitespace into an array, find the indices of the word "JOIN", and then access the following indices after the word "JOIN."

```
$data = Get-Content -Path query1.txt
$indices = @()
$output = @()

$dataarray = $data -split '\s+'
$singleIndex = -1
Do{
    $singleIndex = [array]::IndexOf($dataarray,"JOIN",$singleIndex + 1)
    If($singleIndex -ge 0){$indices += $singleIndex}
}While($singleIndex -ge 0)

foreach ($index in $indices) {
$output += $dataarray[$index + 1]
}
```

Outputs:

> TableB
>
> TableC

You can adjust for capitalization (saw you set your input to all lowercase), etc as needed if you expect varying input files.

Answer (score 2):

Process your data with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-3.0):

```
$data | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern '(?<=join\s+)\S+' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Groups |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

`(?<=...)` is a so-called positive lookbehind assertion that is used for matching the pattern without being included in the returned string (meaning the returned matches are just the table names without the `JOIN` before them).

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked indeed for the case that table is called TableA. In case the word after join would be Table.A as TableA it would not work.

Comment: @Nab Obviously you need to adust the pattern if your table names might contain non-word characters as well. See updated answer.